# Seam - get Connection via (Session)em.getDelegate();

Tags: hibernate, jpa, seam, entitymanager

I use the Seam framework.

If I do

```
Session sess = (Session)em.getDelegate();
Connection conn = sess.connection();
```

Is this then a new connection?
And do I have to close the connection manually?

I tested this in a loop in Weblogic app server:

```
    Session sess = (Session)em.getDelegate();

    for (int i=1; i<=1000; i++) {
        Connection conn = sess.connection();
        // ... 
        //conn.close();
    }
```

And I never saw in the console that the Weblogic pool limit was out of resources and
also no forcing of inactive connections to the pool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the javadoc:

> Get the JDBC connection of this Session. If the session is using aggressive collection release (as in a CMT environment), it is the application's responsibility to close the connection returned by this call. Otherwise, the application should not close the connection.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/index.html?org/hibernate/Session.html